# Integer number too large - Compilation error

Tags: java, integer

Why does this

```
int a = 2147483648;
```

result in this error:

> ```
> Test.java:3: integer number too large: 2147483648
> int a = 2147483648;
>         ^ 1 error
> ```

But this works without that compiler error?

```
int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1;
```

Comment: When you add it rolls over. If you encode it as a constant it doesn't.

Comment: What is the difference between a number that doesn't fit `int` and a number that does? Well ... the first doesn't fit. If you still don't know why the second works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doesn't actually matter that the destination of your assignment is a variable of type `int`, as the following are equally invalid:

```
long x = 2147483648; // <-- literal yields "integer too large" error

System.out.println(2147483648); // <-- same issue
```

The problem is the literal itself, which, without a `L` suffix, is of type `int`. The type of `x` in your first error is not related.

As per [JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) regarding literals:

> It is a compile-time error if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator; or if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648.

This number may not be assigned to an `int`, even though the literal itself is of type `int` as per the spec. However, in the case of `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`, this rule is not violated. `1` is a valid `int`, as is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and their sum wraps around as per [15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.

Note, by the way, that the following is valid:

```
int x = (int)2147483648L;
```

As `2147483648L` *is* a valid `long` literal, and the cast will truncate it to fit in an `int`, yielding the same end value as your `MAX_VALUE + 1` result above in this case (notably, `-2147483648`).

Answer (score 3):

It's because an Integer wraps around when adding to it.

Comment: Please elobarate.

Comment: @Subhan Ahmed Each data type can only store a certain range of values; for example, a byte can only store -128 to 127.  If your byte currently stores 127 and you add 1 to it, it will wrap around and become -128.

Comment: Thanks, @SteveSmith for the explanation. What do you mean by wrap around?

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the end of the main function:

```
System.out.println(a);
```

You'll see that `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1;` "rolls over" to `-2147483648`.